# AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'get' button error [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like to make a test button but it writes me an error shows which I did not find anywhere on the internet

code:

```
@slash.slash(
  name="ButtonTest",
  description='Test a button function (this not work)',
  guild_ids=[894190915097337876]
)
async def _ButtonTest(ctx: SlashContext):
  await ctx.send("test", components = [Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label='sus')])
  instruction=await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("Click"))
  await instruction.send(content='Test button function succeeded!!')
```

error:

```
An exception has occurred while executing command `buttontest`:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 1352, in invoke_command
    await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/model.py", line 210, in invoke
    return await self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 42, in _ButtonTest
    await ctx.send("test", components = [Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label='sus')])
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/context.py", line 215, in send
    if components and not all(comp.get("type") == 1 for comp in components):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/context.py", line 215, in <genexpr>
    if components and not all(comp.get("type") == 1 for comp in components):
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please post the *whole* traceback.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński look now

Comment: Are you using some external library or a fork of dpy like next cord or PyCord?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved the problem or not. Maybe it will help someone.

This error occurs due to slash commands, or rather local ctx. The problem is solved by creating an `async def` function in which messages will be sent. Just do not pass `ctx` to this function, pass only the necessary parameters, if you need to send a message, pass `ctx.channel` (then use `await channel.send()`), if you need a user, then `ctx.author` and ect

Corrected code:

```
@slash.slash(
    name="ButtonTest",
    description='Test a button function (this not work)',
    guild_ids=[894190915097337876]
)
async def _ButtonTest(ctx: SlashContext):
    for_Button_Test(ctx.channel)


async def for_Button_Test(ch):
    await ch.send("test", components=[Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label='sus')])
    instruction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("Click"))
    await instruction.send(content='Test button function succeeded!!')
```